# PHPUnit passing a test with no assertions within config

Tags: phpunit

I want to pass tests which get the following: "This test did not perform any assertions"

I know I could add something like `assertTrue(true)` however is it possible to add something to the config to make these tests pass cleaner?

I'm pretty sure this only happens since version PHPUnit 3.5.0 with the introduction of 
`--strict`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Edit:** You've got a few choices depending on which version you're using, whether you want to ignore *all* risky tests or just a few, and if you want it to be permanent or temporary.

Prior to 5.6, if you didn't want to add bogus assertions to all your tests, you had to avoid passing `--strict` to PHPUnit or add `strict="false"` to your `phpunit.xml`. The point of this option is to "Mark a test as incomplete if no assertions are made."

At some point, PHPUnit added the related `--dont-report-useless-tests` command-line switch and `beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="false"` config option. I haven't checked if they are replacements or additional fine-grained versions.

The above options affect all risky tests. Using them will leave you open to accidentally writing tests without assertions. The following new options are safer as you have to purposefully mark each risky test that you wish to allow.

PHPUnit [5.6](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/445fe8eeb27be9be122b279eb381b8b635e099ea/ChangeLog-5.6.md) added the [`@doesNotPerformAssertions`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.1/annotations.html#doesnotperformassertions) annotation to mark individual test cases as "not risky" even though they perform no assertions.

```
/**
 * @doesNotPerformAssertions
 */
public function testWithoutAsserting() {
    $x = 5;
}
```

PHPUnit [7.2](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/7.2.0/ChangeLog-7.2.md) introduced [`TestCase::expectNotToPerformAssertions()`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3042) which does the same thing.

```
public function testWithoutAsserting() {
    $this->expectNotToPerformAssertions();
    $x = 5;
}
```

Comment: How do I not pass --strict ? I just run phpunit, So I am guessing it is in the config xml correct ?

Comment: Yes, use `strict="false"` in the `<phpunit>` element or simply omit it as the default should be `false`.

Comment: a cleaner way to do it is by putting this line at the beginning of the test `$this->expectNotToPerformAssertions();`

Answer (score 25):

With PHPUnit 7.2 you get another alternative:

```
public function testCodeWithoutUsingAssertions()
{
    $this->expectNotToPerformAssertions();
    // do stuff...
}
```

See also https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3042.

Comment: Supports in PHPUnit 9.* as well.

Answer (score 24):

Use the [`@doesNotPerformAssertions` annotation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.1/annotations.html#doesnotperformassertions):

```
/**
 * @doesNotPerformAssertions
 */
public function testCodeWithoutUsingAssertions()
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't generate coverage for such method

Comment: @simPod Yes, and this is a good thing, because making no assertions simply means you're testing whether an exception is caught or not. And if you've TDD'd correctly, all other code would have been tested by other tests anyway. So you don't need the other coverage.

Comment: @David that's false. I can have a test without assertions. E.g. that some code runs and does not throw. Testing is not only asserting.

Comment: But I need the coverage even when there are no assertions. I don't leak coverage from "all other code" so I know what I have tests specifically written for.

Comment: Supports in PHPUnit 9.* as well.

Answer (score 13):

Make use of `$this->addToAssertionCount(1)`. See below.

```
class NoAssertTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    function testWithoutAssertions() {
        $x = 5;

        // Increment the assertion count to signal this test passed.
        // This is important if you use a @depends on this test
        $this->addToAssertionCount(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have PHP SimpleTest, another approach would be to use:

```
$this->pass();
```

This will mark the test as completed and passed.

On the other hand, for a test that you want to fail, you can use:

```
$this->fail();
```

For example:

```
if (someComplicatedLogicValidation) {
    // Do more stuff and asserts
} else{
    $this->fail();
}
```

I tried this in PHP 5.5 and works:

```
function testThatWorks() {
    $this->pass();
}

function testThatFails() {
    $this->fail();
}
```

Output:

> 1) Fail at [...ExampleTest.unit.php line 23]
>       in testThatFails
>       in ExampleTest
>       in .../ExampleTest.unit.php
>   fail in 3.02s

Maybe the method pass can still be easily implemented in PHPUnit. Source from SimpleTest:

```
function pass($message = "Pass") {
    if (! isset($this->reporter)) {
        trigger_error('Can only make assertions within test methods');
    }
    $this->reporter->paintPass(
    $message . $this->getAssertionLine());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: the method `pass()` doesn't exist in PHPUnit >= 4.4. not sure if it even existed before.

Comment: @awei We are using PHP 5 and it does, and we used to have 4.X and also it does. Will update on Monday with proper version numbers and plugin versions.

Comment: @awei yes, indeed it works, added edit in my answer.

Comment: which version of *PHPUnit* are you using? in version "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.4" this is not working.

Comment: @awei so the thing is that we do use PHPUnit, but it's been wrapped by some classes from SimpleTest.

Comment: that would explain it. Can you paste your SimpleTest->passes() method? I'm curious to see what's in it.

Comment: @awei done at the end of my answer. If that answered you point, please consider your vote.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the test has no assertion because I'm just checking everything using `prophecy` lib to mock and check that methods are being called as expected...

PHPUnit by default expects that test has at least one assertion, and warn you to put it.

Just adding this line in any part of your test is enough.

```
$this->expectNotToPerformAssertions();
```

But also you can design a test that in some cases have assertions or not

```
public function testCodeNoAssertions()
{
    if ($something === true) {
        $this->expectNotToPerformAssertions();
    }
    // do stuff...

    if ($somethingElse === true) {
    //do any assertion
    }
}
```

In conclusion, It's not a bug... It's a feature.

Answer (score 2):

PHPUnit 7.2+. **$this->expectNotToPerformAssertions()** can be used, if you have conditions, that might disable assertions. Seems it is not in the official docs, but can be found here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/3042/files

```
public function testCodeNoAssertions()
{
    $this->expectNotToPerformAssertions();
}
```

At least PHPUnit 7.0+. **@doesNotPerformAssertions** can be used. Current docs do not state when this was added. https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.0/annotations.html#doesnotperformassertions

```
/**
 * @doesNotPerformAssertions
 */
public function testCodeWithoutUsingAssertions()
{

}
```

If your test is simply incomplete, you should be using **$this->markTestIncomplete()** https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.0/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html

```
public function testCodeThatIsIncomplete()
{
    $this->markTestIncomplete('Implementation of this test is not complete.');
}
```

If you want to temporarily disable a test **$this->markTestSkipped()** should be used. https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.0/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#skipping-tests

```
public function testCodeThatIsDisabledTemporarily()
{
    $this->markTestSkipped('This test is disabled to test, if it is interfering with other tests.');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a superclass and placed SimpleTest -like function there:

```
/**
 * Pass a test
 */
public function pass()
{
    //phpunit is missing pass()
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
```

Then you can call it

```
$this->pass();
```